# PHP example for retrieving home_timeline using Twitter API v1.1

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

Can somebody help me in understanding how to retrieve the home timeline of the user. Examples of how this could be used would be perfect, but if that is too much to ask for, then links to tutorials which start at the beginner would also be great which can go through step by step.

Also what other external files would I need to be able to accomplish this?

Comment: http://www.google.com < start here

Answer (score 0):

check this...There are several links also. this might be useful.  http://viralsolani.wordpress.com/2012/05/26/writing-your-first-twitter-application-with-oauth/